# .NET Remoting string comparison behaviour after Windows 10 update

Tags: c#, remoting

I have a .NET remoting client/server application where my remote object has a  method that returns a Dictionary as follows:

```
   public Dictionary<string, string> Test()
    {
        Dictionary<string, string> d = new Dictionary<string, string>(StringComparer.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase);

        d.Add("name", "test");

        return d;
    }
```

When this remote method is called by a client machine running Windows 10 with update 1709 (fall creator's update), the key lookup is no longer case insensitive, i.e. ContainsKey("Name") returns false.

This was not the case before update 1709 or if update 1709 is reverted. Also, if the string comparer is changed to StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase (changing the server side only),  ContainsKey("Name") returns true.

Both client and server are using the same region and language settings (English Ireland en-IE). Has something changed in this Windows update to cause this behaviour?

Comment: What region/language settings are the client and server using?

Comment: @Matthew Watson both are using en-IE (English Ireland)

Comment: The only thing I can think of that could be remotely relevant is that in .Net 4.6, the default locale of a `Task` changed to be that of the calling thread - but I don't think that could be anything to do with it.

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you.

```
public Dictionary<string, string> Test()
{
    Dictionary<string, string> d = new Dictionary<string, string>(StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);

    d.Add("name", "test");

    return d;
}
```

Comment: OP obviously already understands how to work around the issue, as stated in their question. What they're asking is what has changed to make previously working code not work.